# show list of states from database in handlebars template through ajax call

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

i am uisng handlebars template to show my list of states from database via ajax call.
Below is how my code goes.

```
listofplaces:function(){

$.ajax({
         url: 'getStates',
         type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {},
        success: function(response){

         var source = $('#showstateTemplate').html();
         var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
         $('#statecheck').html(template(response));         


        },

    });




},
```

My template is as follows

```
            <script id="showstateTemplate" type="text/template"> 
            <option value="">Select State</option>
            <option value={{'state'}}> {{state}}  </option> 


            </script>
```

The response i get from server is as follows

```
     {"state":[{"state":"Bihar"},{"state":"Assam"},{"state":"Uttar Pradesh"},{"state":"Maharashtra"},{"state":"West Bengal"},{"state":"Andhra Pradesh"},{"state":"Madhya Pradesh"},{"state":"Tamil Nadu"},{"state":"Karnataka"},{"state":"Gujarat"},{"state":"Orissa"},{"state":"Kerala"},{"state":"Jharkhand"},{"state":"Punjab"},{"state":"Haryana"},{"state":"Chhattisgarh"},{"state":"Jammu and Kashmir"},{"state":"Uttarakhand"},{"state":"Himachal Pradesh"},{"state":"Tripura"},{"state":"Meghalaya"},{"state":"Manipur"},{"state":"Nagaland"},{"state":"Goa"},{"state":"Mizoram"},{"state":"Sikkim"},{"state":"Delhi"},{"state":"Pondicherry"},{"state":"Chandigarh"},{"state":"Dadra and Nagar Haveli"},{"state":"Lakshadweep"},{"state":"Arunachal Pradesh"},{"state":"Rajasthan"},{"state":"Daman and Diu"},{"state":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands"}]}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to show the list of states in the template?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the template render at all without error? If you get to that point, the following is how your template should be:

```
<script id="showstateTemplate" type="text/template"> 
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  {{#each state}}
    <option value='{{state}}'>{{state}}</option> 
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for  answering @dc2. I managed to get this working. Yes each helper is required. 'var obj = JSON.parse(response);
      var source = $('#showdstateTemplate').html();
             var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    $('#statecheck').html(template(obj));' got it working